# React render multiple DOM elements from different HTML pages from same index.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm essentially trying to write a JavaScript plugin that can go embed on sites written in react. My issue is I need to be able to render components in DOM elements on different pages without using routing. Here is my code so far..

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import Products from './Products';

const app = (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <App />
    </ApolloProvider>
)

const products = (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <Products />
    </ApolloProvider>
)

ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('root'));
ReactDOM.render(products, document.getElementById('products'));
```

Then when this code is bundled and placed on html page..

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="products.html">Products</a>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="main.f043f60e.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Products.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>

        <div id="products"></div>
        <script src="main.f043f60e.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The contents of my components are not shown. It only works if I have both DOM elements (*products* and *root*) on each page, but that defeats the purpose. How can I accomplish this without having all root elements present on a page?

Comment: React is mainly used to build single page apps. So on each page reload, you are essentially restarting the React app from scratch. You'll need to either have a `root` element on each page or conditionally change your root in your `ReactDOM.render` call in your main app file.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda ok so is there a way to do conditional rendering then without using the url? Like say the user is on the products page and needs to display a list of products. How would I conditionally change root element?

Comment: Hmm, without checking the url? Not sure. Is there a reason you can't use `window.location.pathname` to get the current page?

Comment: You can also target the root element by class, so you could do: `<div id="products" class="root"></div>` and `ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector('.root'));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, the reason your `.render`'s aren't working unless you have both *app* and *products* included as DOM elements is due to an error. i.e. `ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('root'));` can't find an element with ID *root*.

This should work if you continue with the proposed structure:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import Products from './Products';

const app = (
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
  </ApolloProvider>
)

const products = (
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <Products />
  </ApolloProvider>
)

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
if (rootElement) {
  ReactDOM.render(app, rootElement); 
}

const productsElement = document.getElementById('products');
if (productsElement) {
  ReactDOM.render(products, productsElement); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an ideal set up you're looking for when implementing React.
But you can do conditional render logic inside your script :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import Products from './Products';

const app = (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        {window.location.href === "https://www.example.com/app.html " ? <App /> : ''}
        {window.location.href === "https://www.example.com/products.html " ? <Products/> : ''}
    </ApolloProvider>
)

ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('root'));
```

And then change `<body>` in both html ( in app.html and products.html ) to :

```
<body>
    <a href="products.html">Products</a>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="main.f043f60e.js"></script>
</body>
```

Ps. Approach not recommended while using React.

Comment: They are looking for conditional logic for this line: `ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('root'));` not in a component render method